# Why can't I add comments on Stack Exchange The Workplace?

Tags: support, bug

I noticed that, on SE The Workplace I can't leave any comment, not even on my own posts or answers to my own posts. I simply can't see the "add a comment" badge. I have 247 points and verified that I have the privilege of commenting everywhere.

What I have tried:

- Logging out and back in. Did not work.
- Check other SE sites: on the other ones I can comment regoularly.
- Check SE The Workplace from another device: on my phone I can leave comments.

Does anyone have any idea Why I can't leave comments on SE The Workplace while on my PC?

Comment: They changed it from add comment to suggest improvements, it is still just below the post.

Comment: Ok, now I see. This is just for The Workplace right?

Comment: I think so, I have not seen it anywhere else.